# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject get Task List returns Null

Tags: api, json.net

Been looking at this for a few hours now and am struggling to work out how to deserialize the response from a call to a Web API. We had a previous version that worked fine but the Endpoint structure changed after an update to API and as a result the code no longer works.

Basically I am trying to extract the Tasks returned from the results of the API call, see below for a structure of the returned API call from Postman.

```
{
  "Version": 1,
  "Result": "Success",
  "Data": {
    "Order": {
      "Oid": "f3a3afa9-ac2b-4914-b3cb-585c761f2dfb",
      "Did": 265532,
      "Tasks": [
        {
          "Oid": "af82ce50-0587-4752-ba3b-d60dbfebe041",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-05-19T02:24:55.437Z",
          "ChangedOn": "2023-05-19T02:45:26.28Z",
          "Description": "",
          "Comment": "",
          "IsStarted": false,
          "ScheduledOn": "2023-05-19T12:14:51.507",
          "ProductionDeadline": "2023-05-21T16:00:00",
          "ScheduledStart": "2023-05-19T11:56:00",
          "ScheduledEnd": "2023-05-19T12:04:00",
          "RealStart": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "RealEnd": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderItemPartsCount": 27,
          "CalculatedSeconds": "120",
          "IdleSeconds": "0",
          "ScheduledSeconds": 480,
          "RealSeconds": 0,
          "PercentComplete": 0,
          "HasFinishedItems": false,
          "IsCustomTask": false,
          "AppointmentType": "OrderSpecificAppointment",
          "Station": {
            "_Value": "Centurio",
            "oid": "f7f3c5fe-49f0-4a9a-b366-29c4ab990fc7"
          },
          "MasterTask": {
            "_Value": "",
            "oid": "179212f4-ff0e-465d-962c-51b7da711bb7"
          }
        },
        {
          "Oid": "72b6a0ba-cbc2-4f9b-9372-86805d40f7e3",
          "CreatedOn": "2023-05-19T02:24:55.437Z",
          "ChangedOn": "2023-05-19T02:25:28.37Z",
          "Description": "",
          "Comment": "",
          "IsStarted": false,
          "ScheduledOn": "2023-05-19T11:54:55.437",
          "ProductionDeadline": "2023-05-21T16:00:00",
          "ScheduledStart": "2023-05-19T12:11:00",
          "ScheduledEnd": "2023-05-19T13:10:00",
          "RealStart": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "RealEnd": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
          "OrderItemPartsCount": 27,
          "CalculatedSeconds": "3540",
          "IdleSeconds": "0",
          "ScheduledSeconds": 3540,
          "RealSeconds": 0,
          "PercentComplete": 0,
          "HasFinishedItems": false,
          "IsCustomTask": false,
          "AppointmentType": "OrderSpecificAppointment",
          "Station": {
            "_Value": "Twinmatic",
            "oid": "d92a32c3-0763-49d7-a8eb-77ea68afa311"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "Details": ""
}
```

In the previous version there was no "Order" element, can anyone assist in showing how I can get access to the Tasks as a List so I can process them?

Regards
Peter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like https://jsonutils.com to transform JSON into boilerplate code for deserializing your object.

I used it over your JSON and that gave me a whole heap of classes and from there, I was able to put this very  basic program together that does the deserialization (*taking note that you may want to clean it up by changing variable names to conform to naming standards and also refactoring, etc.*) ...

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace StackoverflowAnswer
{
    public class Station
    {
        public string _Value { get; set; }
        public string oid { get; set; }
    }

    public class MasterTask
    {
        public string _Value { get; set; }
        public string oid { get; set; }
    }

    public class TaskResponse
    {
        public string Oid { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ChangedOn { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public bool IsStarted { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScheduledOn { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProductionDeadline { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScheduledStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime ScheduledEnd { get; set; }
        public DateTime RealStart { get; set; }
        public DateTime RealEnd { get; set; }
        public int OrderItemPartsCount { get; set; }
        public string CalculatedSeconds { get; set; }
        public string IdleSeconds { get; set; }
        public int ScheduledSeconds { get; set; }
        public int RealSeconds { get; set; }
        public int PercentComplete { get; set; }
        public bool HasFinishedItems { get; set; }
        public bool IsCustomTask { get; set; }
        public string AppointmentType { get; set; }
        public Station Station { get; set; }
        public MasterTask MasterTask { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public string Oid { get; set; }
        public int Did { get; set; }
        public IList<TaskResponse> Tasks { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public string Result { get; set; }
        public Data Data { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MainAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task MainAsync()
        {
            var json = "{\"Version\":1,\"Result\":\"Success\",\"Data\":{\"Order\":{\"Oid\":\"f3a3afa9-ac2b-4914-b3cb-585c761f2dfb\",\"Did\":265532,\"Tasks\":[{\"Oid\":\"af82ce50-0587-4752-ba3b-d60dbfebe041\",\"CreatedOn\":\"2023-05-19T02:24:55.437Z\",\"ChangedOn\":\"2023-05-19T02:45:26.28Z\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"IsStarted\":false,\"ScheduledOn\":\"2023-05-19T12:14:51.507\",\"ProductionDeadline\":\"2023-05-21T16:00:00\",\"ScheduledStart\":\"2023-05-19T11:56:00\",\"ScheduledEnd\":\"2023-05-19T12:04:00\",\"RealStart\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"RealEnd\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"OrderItemPartsCount\":27,\"CalculatedSeconds\":\"120\",\"IdleSeconds\":\"0\",\"ScheduledSeconds\":480,\"RealSeconds\":0,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"HasFinishedItems\":false,\"IsCustomTask\":false,\"AppointmentType\":\"OrderSpecificAppointment\",\"Station\":{\"_Value\":\"Centurio\",\"oid\":\"f7f3c5fe-49f0-4a9a-b366-29c4ab990fc7\"},\"MasterTask\":{\"_Value\":\"\",\"oid\":\"179212f4-ff0e-465d-962c-51b7da711bb7\"}},{\"Oid\":\"72b6a0ba-cbc2-4f9b-9372-86805d40f7e3\",\"CreatedOn\":\"2023-05-19T02:24:55.437Z\",\"ChangedOn\":\"2023-05-19T02:25:28.37Z\",\"Description\":\"\",\"Comment\":\"\",\"IsStarted\":false,\"ScheduledOn\":\"2023-05-19T11:54:55.437\",\"ProductionDeadline\":\"2023-05-21T16:00:00\",\"ScheduledStart\":\"2023-05-19T12:11:00\",\"ScheduledEnd\":\"2023-05-19T13:10:00\",\"RealStart\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"RealEnd\":\"0001-01-01T00:00:00\",\"OrderItemPartsCount\":27,\"CalculatedSeconds\":\"3540\",\"IdleSeconds\":\"0\",\"ScheduledSeconds\":3540,\"RealSeconds\":0,\"PercentComplete\":0,\"HasFinishedItems\":false,\"IsCustomTask\":false,\"AppointmentType\":\"OrderSpecificAppointment\",\"Station\":{\"_Value\":\"Twinmatic\",\"oid\":\"d92a32c3-0763-49d7-a8eb-77ea68afa311\"}}]}},\"Details\":\"\"}";

            var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);

            // Break here            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response, this looks really good and I'll give it a try. I tried working up something similar but it didn't work.